# How to make dropdown jQuery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this dropdown menu that work in jsFiddle when i test it but when i run it to my testing server, its not working like how it supposed to.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cyberjo50/39bu8/2/

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="toggle.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<button>Select Destinations<img src="images/down-arrow.png" width="20" height="20" alt=""   style="vertical-align:middle; padding-top: 0px;"/></button> 
<nav id="menu">     
<a href="#">Philadelphia</a>
<a href="#">United States of America</a>
<a href="#">Philippines</a>
<a href="#">Long Destinations Names</a>
<a href="#">Some Destination</a>
<a href="#">Australia</a>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
img_arrow = '<img src="images/down-arrow.png" width="20" height="20"/>';

$(function ()
{
var $window = $(window),
    $nav = $('nav'),
    $button = $('button');

$button.on('click', function ()
{
    $nav.slideToggle();
});

$window.on('resize', function ()
{
    if ($window.width() > 320)
    {
        $nav.show();
    }
});
});
$('#menu a').click(function(e){

$('button').html($(this).html() + img_arrow);

e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is my test page:
http://t4fresponsivelandingpage.businesscatalyst.com/test.html#

Not sure why its not working on my test page. Its supposed to work like the one in Jsfiddle. the code from fiddle is exactly the one im using in my testing link.

Comment: It's just works on my browser.. I'm using chrome

Comment: It works fine on my browser (Chrome).

Comment: I am using Chrome and it doesn't work.  Both jfiddle and test page show the same results.  when I click on the button, a bunch of links show up in one horizontal line. When I click on the button again, the links disappear.  Is this what you expected?  I guess not because a drop down is supposed to list items vertically.  Is the dropdown supposed to be formatted by a CSS? if so, no css is being linked.  The one (ModuleStyleSheets.css) on your test page is throwing a 404.

Comment: You've reposted the problem twice.  Instead of posting another question, edit your last one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop-down menu list isn't responding when i click 1 of the buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789559/drop-down-menu-list-isnt-responding-when-i-click-1-of-the-buttons)

Comment: A more appropriately formatted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39bu8/3/

Comment: The buttons should replace the title "Select destinations" to whatever is selected ex. "Philadelphia". the fiddle just works fine.but when upload it to my server ,the buttons wont replace the title.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Err, more like http://jsfiddle.net/39bu8/5/ :)

Comment: Thank you all ! JarredFarrish code fixed the problem.

Comment: I have 2 <button> tag inside my html and its afecting the other button. how do i target only 1 button with id/class of "button_01" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running the click handler during page load instead of after it. `$(function(){})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready()`. To fix the click issue, move the `click` handler assignment to inside the `onDOMReady` call:

```
$(function (){
    var $window = $(window),
        $nav = $('nav'),
        $button = $('button');

    $button.on('click', function (){
        $nav.slideToggle();
    });

    $window.on('resize', function (){
        if ($window.width() > 320){
            $nav.show();
        }
    });

    $('#menu a').click(function(e){
        $('button').html($(this).html() + img_arrow);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39bu8/4/

Comment: I have 2 <button> tag inside my html and its afecting the other button. how do i target only 1 button with id/class of "button_01" ?